# What's the best Database solution for millions of records?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, database-optimization

Actually we use a MYSQL database that contain tables with over than 15 000 000 records , so we noticed that the queries are very slow, it's normal :D, but we are looking for optimizing our services .

Bear in mind that we have indexed all the needed fields, and we use memcache to add some help,
Our SERVER Machine has the following configuration :

`model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5630  @ 2.53GHz`

So my question is : Is there any one in the same case and what's the best DBMS for my case?

I will be glade to receive your suggestions .

Thank you.

All the best.

Comment: 15 million records is not considered big these days. Any of the popular DBMS can easily handle that - (if properly designed and tuned) including MySQL. Although I would always prefer Postgres over MySQL due to a much richer (SQL) feature set.

Comment: Are logging slow queries? Also, I *always* keep beer in mind ...

Comment: I agree with a_horse_with_no_name (that was fun to type), 15 million records really isn't a lot these days. Slow performing queries can mean amultitude of things, not necessarily using the wrong DBMS.  How much RAM are we talking here?

Comment: I have heard that noSql has a good effect on large scale database, (MongoDB ...)

Comment: For RAM configuration we have 6 GO of memory

Comment: If you have queries that are running slowly, you should ask a particular question about those queries.  MySQL does a poor job with certain types of optimizations, although you can usually get it to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL can certainly cope with 15M records. If there's a problem, it's not that you're using the wrong DBMS.

If you really have indexed everything you need to index, you could also check whether your machine has enough RAM in it. That's probably going to be more important than the CPU.

Comment: MemTotal:        6114220 kB
MemFree:         2237348 kB
Buffers:            4720 kB
Cached:           187184 kB
SwapCached:        37644 kB
Active:          1653368 kB
Inactive:        1188172 kB
Active(anon):    1640300 kB
Inactive(anon):  1009412 kB